# derived map from short exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

Given an short exact sequence of (coherent) sheaves $0 \to A \xrightarrow f B \xrightarrow g B \to 0$, on a (smooth) projective variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, one can build a long exact sequence of cohomology groups (that turn out to be just vector spaces in this case)

$0 \to H^0(X,A) \xrightarrow{\Gamma(f)} H^0(X,B)\xrightarrow{\Gamma(g)} H^0(X,C)\xrightarrow{\delta} H^1(X,A) \xrightarrow{R^1\Gamma(f)} H^1(X,B)\xrightarrow{R^1\Gamma(g)} H^1(X,B) \to \cdots$

where $\delta$ is a $\delta$ fuctor (see Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry book, Chapter III) $\Gamma$ is the global section functor and $R^i(f)$ is the $i$-th derived of $f$.

I would like to know if there is a effective method to compute the $\delta$ functor and $R^i(f)$ (or  $R^i(f)$ for some specific cases, for instance when $A,B$ and $C$ are sums of line bundles (hence the maps $f$ and $g$ are just matrices with polynomial entries).

For instante, let $X = \mathbb{P}^n$ and fix an hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ we have the restriction sequence:

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1) \xrightarrow{\times H} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{H} \to 0$$

Hartshorne says (page 227) that we have the following:

$$H^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\otimes \mathcal{O}_{H}) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^n(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1))\xrightarrow{\times H} H^n(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n})\to 0$$

and that $\delta$ is the "division" by $H$. I would like to understand why is that.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I known that having the matrices $f$ and $g$ for the case where the sheaves are sums of line bundles, I can compute the matrix of the maps in the vector spaces, but I am looking for a more insightfull way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried chasing through the proof of the snake lemma in this particular case?

Comment: Also, the rightmost cohomology group in your last displayed sequence should be $H^n(\mathbb P^n, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n})$.

Comment: Dear @TabesBridges yes yes, I know I can prove that those maps fit into the exact sequence of cohomology, the problem is that why they are precisely the maps appearing in the long exact sequente of cohomology, in other words, why they the derived maps. I corrected the typo in the cohomology group, thanks.

Comment: If you are just dealing with very nice schemes (for which Cech=Derived functor cohomology), you can "see" what the induced maps on cohomology are easily using Cech cocyles.